# How do I access sound files from other folders in python?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm a beginner programmer right now and am using the pygame "Mixer" module to call sound files from the directory. When I move them to a separate "Audio" folder they cannot be called without more direction, how would I specify that the sound files are in a specific folder in the directory?

I want my folder setup to resemble this:

```
DirectoryFolder:
    Audio:
        shoot.wav
    src.py
```

```py
shoot_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('shoot.wav')
```

This only loads the audio if its in the same parent folder as the main .py file.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the join() function of the ‘os’ module to access files in other directories. Example:

1. File structure

```
MyGame
    -code
        -src.py

    -audio
        -shoot.wav
```

2. Code:

```
import os

#other code

path = os.path.join('..', 'audio', 'shoot.wav')

shoot_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(path)

#other code
```

The join() function returns a string containing all the arguments concatenated together using forward slashes. Passing '..' as an argument means to go up a level in the directory. In the code, the os.path.join() returns the following string:

```
../audio/shoot.wav
```

This path tells the script to go up one folder from the ‘code’ folder, which means into the ‘MyGame’ folder. Then, the script goes into the ‘audio’ folder and accesses the sound file.

Comment: Thank you so much! The only things I had to change is it kept returning a branch error whenever I used the '..', removing it entirely seems to have fixed it though

Comment: @cloverless08 You’re welcome! I just wanted to let you know the use of ‘..’ In your file structure you actually don’t need it. If you use ‘..’ , the script will go up one level; out of the DirectoryFolder. That’s why you get a branch error. For your file structure, the path would be os.path.join('Audio', 'shoot.wav')